# How can i load test a post API using 'loadtest' nodejs module?

Tags: json, node.js, post, load-testing, stress-testing

I am using the loadtest nodejs module to test stress testing on APIs in nodejs script. The Get call syntax is working however post call not. the code is below.

```
function optionsObject() {
  return { 
  url: 'http://localhost:3000/api/v2/signup',
  maxRequests: 1,
  concurrency: 1,
  method: 'POST',
  contentType: 'applicaton/json',
  body: {
     password: 'test',
     email: 'testobject_1@signup2.com',
     name: 'kPYgJ6Rg5wnExt8hTXQIHDn2LaCMsytjhQzp' 
        }
   }
```

}

```
loadtest.loadTest(optionsObject(), function (error, result) {
            if (error) {
             console.log('Got an error: %s', error);
            } else {
             console.log(result);
              }
            });

            Results:
                {
                 totalRequests: 1,
                 totalErrors: 1,
                 totalTimeSeconds: 0.025545716,
                 rps: 39,
                 meanLatencyMs: 20,
                 maxLatencyMs: 20,
                 percentiles: { '50': 20, '90': 20, '95': 20, '99': 20 },
                 errorCodes: { '400': 1 } 
                 }
```

can anyone help that why i am getting bad request error 400?

Answer (score 7):

there is a typo at the declaration of the Content-Type. (The second i is missing.)

Use

```
contentType: 'application/json',
```

instead, then it works.